Why WMS and vector layers are not visible in EPSG:3879?
I have added WMS layers and vector layers in the Finnish coordinate system ETRS-GK25 EPSG-3879, which is the coordinate system used by the source of data. However, QGIS doesn't want to show these.
There were no problems when downloading. The layers are visible in the layer list, and no errors are shown. When opening the created layout in proper scale, layers are not visible there either.
What can I do? Working on QGIS 3.34.13

Works for me. I tried this WMS service https://kartta.hel.fi/ws/geoserver/avoindata/wms with EPSG:3879 with couple of layers. I set both the project CRS and the CRS for the service request into EPSG:3879.

If you move the layer to the very top, does it show up?  Is your layer a geopackage?

I started to get "connection refused" errors from the above mentioned server. Is it perhaps the same that you are using?
